# svn find file with different revision

Tags: svn

I have a basic SVN repository and this scenario:

I have a shared server using SVN to update the source code. At first I update the whole repo using `svn up` to the lastest revision, ex: `12`. But few time after someone (do not ask me why) use `svn up -rXX` (where XX != `12`) on just 1 file.

```
svn up -r10 public/style.css
```

I come back to the folder and when I use `svn info` the revision is always `12` but I need to list all file with different revision than the root folder?

I'm looking for a better solution that glob all files and using svn info :)

Comment: three questions:
Why use mixed-revision working copies?
Why use a shared working copy?
What OS is the server?

Comment: For the two first questions like I said do not ask me why :) I don't have the choice atm. Linux.

Comment: I hear you, I work for a living too.  Keep fighting the good fight.  Is prod served up out of this working copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first - start fighting the uphill battle to get out of the mess you've been thrown into.  You should be able to sell the risks up the chain of the shared and mixed working copy.

you can do something like this from your working copy

`svn status -v | grep -v 12`

to list the rev on all files in the working copy and print those that don't have a 12

Comment: Thanks perfect. I know the situation is worse than bad but atm I don't have choice and I try to maintain as possible I can with this situation :)

Comment: This isn't a wrong solution - it's not a solution at all, it's actually an additional problem.  I think OP realizes this.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to list all file with different revision than the root folder?

No, you **don't need** this - do not confuse the terms "Repository Revision" (global) and "File revision" (for any versioned and changed during time file)

- **Global revision** is slice of history for *all objects in repository* at some moment (and their revision may differ, just because stored in repository change /revision/ *may affect not every file*)
- **File revision** is state of this file at some moment (and file with unchanged own revision may and can exist in different global revisions)

  > svn ls -v http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/

  ```
   36 lazybadg              янв 09 11:45 ./

   34 lazybadg           42 мар 24  2012 Dr?p?r.ma?ar.sv?nskan.man.eller.smalensk?n.txt

   32 lazybadg           88 дек 27  2011 Hello.de.txt

   33 lazybadg           82 фев 28  2012 Hello.en.txt

   36 lazybadg           88 янв 09 11:45 Hello.eo.txt

   35 lazybadg           90 янв 09 11:35 Hello.fr.txt
  ```

(as you can see, in HEAD of trunk files have different revisions - and it's OK)

```
>svn info http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/
...
Revision: 37
...
Last Changed Rev: 36
...
```

If you want return you Working Copy to the state of repository r12 from current Mixed, you have just `svn up -r 12` or, if 12 if HEAD - `svn up`

**Demonstration of process (for the same URL as above)**

```
>svn co http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/
A    trunk\Dr?p?r.ma?ar.sv?nskan.man.eller.smalensk?n.txt
A    trunk\Hello.en.txt
A    trunk\Hello.eo.txt
A    trunk\Hello.fr.txt
A    trunk\Hello.de.txt
 U   trunk
Checked out revision 37.
```

*Mix our WC*

```
>svn up -r 30 Hello.de.txt
Updating 'Hello.de.txt':
U    Hello.de.txt
Updated to revision 30.
```

(we updated file to the state, in which it was at the *repository revision* 30, Hello.de.txt revision may be <= 30)

*Check WC*

```
>svn status
```

(No output - WC is Clean, can be updated without headache)

*Return to pure HEAD*

```
>svn up
Updating '.':
U    Hello.de.txt
Updated to revision 37.
```

(again: 37 is revision of repo, in this state Hello.de.txt may /and have/ own revision - 32 according to ls - but we can do not know this revision exactly, Subversion store this data for us and use when needed)